# jQuery append value of text field to list on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, append, textinput

I'm trying to create an extremely simple comment form for a demo; add some text in a text field, submit, add value to a list. It works when I use a button and an on click event like so:

```
<script>
$(".add-comment").click(function (e) {
var add = $('#comment-body').val();
$('.comments').append('<li>' + '<h4>Name</h4> ' + add + '</li>');
});
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" id="comment-body" />
<button type="button" class="add-comment">Submit</button>
</form>
<ol class="comments"></ol>
```

But this is for a mobile demo, so I don't want a button at all. I just want the comment to be posted when the user hits the return key. I tried removing the button, and editing the script like so, but it doesn't work:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
var add = $('#comment-body').val();
$('.comments').append('<li>' + '<h4>Name</h4> ' + add + '</li>');
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for anyone who stumbles on this in the future, there's a far easier way to do it. All you need to do is detect when someone hits the enter key. You don't need to use a form at all. Here it is:

```
<ol class="comments"></ol>     
<input type="text" id="comment-body" placeholder="add comment here" />          
<script>     
$('#comment-body').keydown(function (e){     
if(e.keyCode == 13){     
var add = $('#comment-body').val();     
$('.comments').append('<li>' + '<h4>Name</h4> ' + add + '</li>');     
}})     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit the page is reloaded, because you submit the page to the server, so you have 2 options:

**1)** You reload all comments when you reload the page (on the server)
**2)** Use async submit (AJAX) and in the callback add the comments

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Sadly it's outside my skill level. I'll look for a comments plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<button type="button" class="add-comment">Submit</button>
```

to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="add-comment">Submit</button>
```

---

`type="submit"` will submit the form.

---

Also you don't have a `action` attribute to your form so this will submit to your current page.